# Bulk updating without type using elastic search py

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to do a bulk insert using elastic search py, but I don't want to specify a type, but it won't allow me to specify None or "" for the value of type. How can I get around this?

```
bulk_data = []

this_merchant_product = {'field1': 'value1'}

op_dict = {
    "index": {
        "_index": "product",
        "_type": None,
        "_id": str(this_merchant_product_id)
    }
}

bulk_data.append(op_dict)
bulk_data.append(this_merchant_product)

es = Elasticsearch()
res = es.bulk(index='product', body=bulk_data)
```

I've also tried to set `_type` to "", but that doesn't work either.

These are the error messages.

This is the error when I set `_type` to None:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'action_request_validation_exception', 'Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;
```

and this is the error I get when I set `_type` to "":

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name cannot be empty string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each index has one mapping type in `Elasticsearch 6.x+`. In `Elasticsearch 7.x+` type is removed. In version `2.x - 5.6` you could have used more then one mapping. Assuming that you’re using version `6.x`, you need to have type of documents in index.

Comment: Gotcha. It looks like the default type is "_doc" if you use elasticsearch-py, in case anyone finds that useful in the future. That's the only value for type that doesn't give me an error.